# iOS UIScrollView contentOffset and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm laying out a fairly complex view hierarchy programmatically, using numerous `addConstraint:` calls. Everything looks and works as expected, however, certain actions result in a warning message in debugger along the lines of:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
... details of the constrains ...
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

When I set the breakpoint as suggested by the debugger, I traced the warning to a call that sets `contentOffset` of one my `UIScrollView`. The debugger says:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint ...
```

But visually, it does not appear that the constraint is being broken, everything still looks correct.

Why would a change in a scrollView's `contentOffset` change anything related to constraints? Why would the debugger complain even if I cannot see anything going wrong on the screen?

***Edit***: this has to do with the fact that constrains on `UIScrollView` relate to its `contentSize` instead of `bounds` for all other views. I had a view that had constrains within its superview (which was a scrollView) and another view outside of the scrollView. When `contentOffset` changes it became impossible to satisfy both of these.

Answer (score 0):

The details of the constraints section is important to you. From the area you traced the issue to, it's probably a width/height constraint issue with the scrollview; however, you'll be able to see which constraints are the issue by looking at the numbers in the brackets of the constraint details.

Please post the whole block.